# JQuery load failed randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have a following JQuery block.  It reads the XML and reads something and shows something when success as below:

```
    <script src="/JS/jQuery-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://www.servername.com/help/timht.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function (xml) {
                //do something
                alert('xml loaded successfully');
            },  //end success
            error: function () {
                alert('failed to load xml');
            }
       });  //end .ajax
    });
    //]]></script>
```

It is straight forward.  When the page is load, the failure pop up shows randomly.   I wonder what caused the problem when loading the timht.xml file.  The xml file itself is small (about 10kb).

Is there any idea?

Thanks
JPL

Comment: You seem have an extra }); after alert('xml loaded...

Comment: Sorry, artm, I removed something in that block and forgot to remove the extra }); as you mentioned.  Edited....

Comment: Is the xml on the same domain as this script?  If it's not then that's why it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turned out that the site behind the F5 load balance.   There are 5 web servers behind F5.  Updated all 5 did solve the problem.

Sometimes, it is not just the codes itself, the server env. costs us tons of effort! :)

Thanks all for your input.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The function you set as the error handler accepts three parameters,
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
(mind the section that discusses the error handler).
The second parameter is the error string.

So, instead of

```
...
error:function () {
...
```

use

```
...
error:function(xhrObj, errorstr){
    alert('failed to load xml due to '+errorstr);
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks Andrija, followed yours and here is I got (randomly):  "failed to load xml due to error" message! Doesn't tell the detailed error.

Comment: @JPL xhrObj object sometimes have additional data, check its  
status
statusText
responseXML and/or responseText properties as well. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR